# Showing a select2 after it's been called on a hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a `<select>` element that is hidden. I called `.select2()` on it. Now I want to show it, but showing the actual element does not translate to showing the select2 element. I'm thinking there's a function I can use like `$("#elem").select2("show")`, but I'm not getting the right one. How do I show this select2 widget (without showing the actual `<select>` first)?

Apologies if this is the dumbest question ever but I can find nothing on it.

Comment: I had the exact same issue with the select2 before i think i solved it by using  `visibility: hidden` instead not sure though.

Comment: @Maantje Haven't tested this but I can't use `visibility: hidden` due to the supposedly hidden select element taking up space.

Comment: Well another way to do it possibly but a little ugly is to call select2 then with a `setTimeout()`  set it to `display: none`.

Comment: The "select2" plugin does not transform the actual `<select>` element. It hides it and creates a styled `<span>` right after it. Try `$('#elem').next().show();`.

Comment: @blex Thank you, this did the trick. In the version I'm using (3.5.2) `$("#elem").prev().show()` is the right code. Would you mind making your comment an answer?